# How to parse mustache with Boost.Xpressive correctly?

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, mustache, boost-xpressive

I have tried to write a **mustache parser** with the excellent [Boost.XPressive](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/xpressive/user_s_guide.html) from the brilliant *Eric Niebler*. But since this is my first parser I am not familiar with the "normal" approach and lingo of compiler writers and feel a bit lost after a few days of trial&error. So I come here and hope someone can tell me the foolishness of my n00bish ways ;)

This is the HTML code with the mustache templates that I want to extract (http://mustache.github.io/):
`Now <bold>is the {{#time}}gugus {{zeit}} oder nicht{{/time}} <i>for all good men</i> to come to the {007} aid of their</bold> {{country}}. Result: {{#Res1}}Nullum <b>est</b> mundi{{/Res1}}`

#### I have the following problems that I couldn't yet solve alone:

- The parser I wrote doesn't print out anything but also doesn't issue a warning at compile-time. I managed before to have it print out parts of the mustache code but never all of it correctly.
- I don't know how I can loop through all the code to find all occurrences but then also access them like with the `smatch what;` variable. The doc only shows how to find the first occurrence with "what" or how to output all the occurrences with the "iterator".

  - Actually I need a combination of both. Because once something is found I need to question the tags name and the content between the tags (which "what" would offer but the "iterator" won't allow) - and act accordingly. I guess I could use "actions" but how?
  - I think that it should be possible to do the tag finding and "content between tags" in one swoop, right? Or do I need to parser 2 times for that - and if so how?
- Is it okay to parse the opening and closing brackets like I did, since there are *always* 2 brackets? Or should I do it in sequence or use `repeat<2,2>('{')`?
- I still feel a bit unsure about the cases where `keep()` and `by_ref()` are necessary and when better not to use them.
- I couldn't find the other options of the 4th parameter of the iterator `sregex_token_iterator cur( str.begin(), str.end(), html, -1 );` here **-1** which outputs all except the matching tags.
- Is my parser string correctly finding nested mustache tags?

```cpp
#include <boost/xpressive/xpressive_static.hpp>
#include <boost/xpressive/match_results.hpp>
typedef std::string::const_iterator It;
using namespace boost::xpressive;

std::string str = "Now <bold>is the {{#time}}gugus {{zeit}} oder nicht{{/time}} <i>for all good men</i> to come to the {007} aid of their</bold> {{country}}. Result: {{#Res1}}Nullum <b>est</b> mundi{{/Res1}}";
// Parser setup --------------------------------------------------------
mark_tag mtag (1), cond_mtag (2), user_str (3);
sregex brackets = "{{"
                  >> keep ( mtag = repeat<1, 20> (_w) )
                  >> "}}"
                  ;

sregex cond_brackets = "{{#"
                   >> keep (cond_mtag = repeat<1, 20> (_w) )
                   >> "}}"
                   >> * (
                       keep (user_str = + (*_s >> +alnum >> *_s) ) |
                       by_ref (brackets) |
                       by_ref (cond_brackets)
                   )
                   >> "{{/"
                   >> cond_mtag
                   >> "}}"
                   ;
sregex mexpression = *( by_ref (cond_brackets) | by_ref (brackets) );

// Looping + catching the results --------------------------------------
smatch what2;
std::cout << "\nregex_search:\n" << str << '\n';
It strBegin = str.begin(), strEnd = str.end();
int ic = 0;

do
{
    if ( !regex_search ( strBegin, strEnd, what2, mexpression ) )
    {
        std::cout << "\t>> Breakout of this life...! Exit after " << ic << " loop(s)." << std::endl;
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "**Loop Nr: " << ic << '\n';
        std::cout << "\twhat2[0] "         << what2[0]      << '\n'; // whole match
        std::cout << "\twhat2[mtag] "      << what2[mtag]   << '\n';
        std::cout << "\twhat2[cond_mtag] " << what2[cond_mtag]   << '\n';
        std::cout << "\twhat2[user_str] "  << what2[user_str]    << '\n';
        // display the nested results
        std::for_each (
            what2.nested_results().begin(),
            what2.nested_results().end(),
            output_nested_results() // <--identical function from E.Nieblers documentation
        );

        strBegin = what2[0].second;
    }
    ++ic;
}
while (ic < 6 || strBegin != str.end() );
```

Comment: According to [the docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/xpressive/user_s_guide.html#boost_xpressive.user_s_guide.grammars_and_nested_matches), boost.xpressive can be used to parse regular and context-free grammars. Are you sure this is powerful enough?

Comment: No not at all, as I said I'm a parser beginner. But mustache seems like a fairly simple EDSL to me and so I thought XPressive could handle it. Certainly Spirit can do it, but I shy away from using it if I don't have to at this point of development. So can you or anyone else give me a clear answer to your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the correct full code from @sehe that now works under GCC >4.8 and CLANG under Linux and Windows. Again many thanks mate for this awesome help, even though this means that I can bury XPressive :D

The following lines have changed or been added:

```
// --
#define BOOST_RESULT_OF_USE_DECLTYPE
// --
struct to_string_f {
template <typename T>
std::string operator()(T const& v) const { return v.to_string(); }};
// --
section     %= "{{" >> sense >> reference [ section_id = to_string(_1) ] >> "}}"
                >> sequence // contents
                > ("{{" >> ('/' >> lexeme [ lit(section_id) ]) >> "}}");
// --
phx::function<to_string_f> to_string;
```

```cpp
//#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#define BOOST_RESULT_OF_USE_DECLTYPE
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_USE_PHOENIX_V3
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/struct.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/utility/string_ref.hpp>
#include <functional>
#include <map>

namespace mustache {

    // any atom refers directly to source iterators for efficiency
    using boost::string_ref;
    template <typename Kind> struct atom {
        string_ref value;

        atom() { }
        atom(string_ref const& value) : value(value) { }

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, atom const& v) { return os << typeid(v).name() << "[" << v.value << "]"; }
    };

    // the atoms
    using verbatim = atom<struct verbatim_tag>;
    using variable = atom<struct variable_tag>;
    using partial  = atom<struct partial_tag>;

    // the template elements (any atom or a section)
    struct section;

    using melement = boost::variant<
            verbatim,
            variable,
            partial, // TODO comments and set-separators
            boost::recursive_wrapper<section>
        >;

    // the template: sequences of elements
    using sequence = std::vector<melement>;

    // section: recursively define to contain a template sequence
    struct section {
        bool       sense; // positive or negative
        string_ref control;
        sequence   content;
    };
}

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(mustache::section, (bool, sense)(boost::string_ref, control)(mustache::sequence, content))

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace phx= boost::phoenix;

struct to_string_f {
    template <typename T>
    std::string operator()(T const& v) const { return v.to_string(); }
};

template <typename Iterator>
    struct mustache_grammar : qi::grammar<Iterator, mustache::sequence()>
{
    mustache_grammar() : mustache_grammar::base_type(sequence)
    {
        using namespace qi;
        static const _a_type section_id = {}; // local
        using boost::phoenix::construct;
        using boost::phoenix::begin;
        using boost::phoenix::size;

        sequence     = *element;
        element      = 
                    !(lit("{{") >> '/') >> // section-end ends the current sequence
                    (partial | section | variable | verbatim);

        reference    = raw [ lexeme [ +(graph - "}}") ] ]
                        [ _val = construct<boost::string_ref>(&*begin(_1), size(_1)) ];

        partial      = qi::lit("{{") >> "> " >> reference >> "}}";

        sense        = ('#' > attr(true))
                     | ('^' > attr(false));

        section     %= "{{" >> sense >> reference [ section_id = to_string(_1) ] >> "}}"
                    >> sequence // contents
                    > ("{{" >> ('/' >> lexeme [ lit(section_id) ]) >> "}}");

        variable     = "{{" >> reference >> "}}";

        verbatim     = raw [ lexeme [ +(char_ - "{{") ] ]
                        [ _val = construct<boost::string_ref>(&*begin(_1), size(_1)) ];

        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES(
                (sequence)(element)(partial)(variable)(section)(verbatim)
                (reference)(sense)
            )
    }
  private:
    phx::function<to_string_f> to_string;
    qi::rule<Iterator, mustache::sequence()> sequence;
    qi::rule<Iterator, mustache::melement()> element;
    qi::rule<Iterator, mustache::partial()>  partial;
    qi::rule<Iterator, mustache::section(), qi::locals<std::string> >  section;
    qi::rule<Iterator, bool()>                sense;                  // postive  or negative
    qi::rule<Iterator, mustache::variable()> variable;
    qi::rule<Iterator, mustache::verbatim()> verbatim;
    qi::rule<Iterator, boost::string_ref()>   reference;
};

namespace Dumping {
    struct dumper : boost::static_visitor<std::ostream&>
    {
        std::ostream& operator()(std::ostream& os, mustache::sequence const& v) const {
            for(auto& element : v)
                boost::apply_visitor(std::bind(dumper(), std::ref(os), std::placeholders::_1), element);
            return os;
        }
        std::ostream& operator()(std::ostream& os, mustache::verbatim const& v) const {
            return os << v.value;
        }
        std::ostream& operator()(std::ostream& os, mustache::variable const& v) const {
            return os << "{{" << v.value << "}}";
        }
        std::ostream& operator()(std::ostream& os, mustache::partial const& v) const {
            return os << "{{> " << v.value << "}}";
        }
        std::ostream& operator()(std::ostream& os, mustache::section const& v) const {
            os << "{{" << (v.sense?'#':'^') << v.control << "}}";
            (*this)(os, v.content);
            return os << "{{/" << v.control << "}}";
        }
    };
}

namespace ContextExpander {

    struct Nil { };

    using Value = boost::make_recursive_variant<
        Nil,
        double,
        std::string,
        std::map<std::string, boost::recursive_variant_>,
        std::vector<boost::recursive_variant_>
    >::type;

    using Dict  = std::map<std::string, Value>;
    using Array = std::vector<Value>;

    static inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Nil   const&)   { return os << "#NIL#"; }
    static inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Dict  const& v) { return os << "#DICT("  << v.size() << ")#"; }
    static inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Array const& v) { return os << "#ARRAY(" << v.size() << ")#"; }

    struct expander : boost::static_visitor<std::ostream&>
    {
        std::ostream& operator()(std::ostream& os, Value const& ctx, mustache::sequence const& v) const {
            for(auto& element : v)
                boost::apply_visitor(std::bind(expander(), std::ref(os), std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2), ctx, element);
            return os;
        }

        template <typename Ctx>
        std::ostream& operator()(std::ostream& os, Ctx const&/*ignored*/, mustache::verbatim const& v) const {
            return os << v.value;
        }

        std::ostream& operator()(std::ostream& os, Dict const& ctx, mustache::variable const& v) const {
            auto it = ctx.find(v.value.to_string());
            if (it != ctx.end())
                os << it->second;
            return os;
        }

        template <typename Ctx>
        std::ostream& operator()(std::ostream& os, Ctx const&, mustache::variable const&) const {
            return os;
        }

        std::ostream& operator()(std::ostream& os, Dict const& ctx, mustache::partial const& v) const {
            auto it = ctx.find(v.value.to_string());
            if (it != ctx.end())
            {
                static const mustache_grammar<std::string::const_iterator> p;

                auto const& subtemplate = boost::get<std::string>(it->second);
                std::string::const_iterator first = subtemplate.begin(), last = subtemplate.end();

                mustache::sequence dynamic_template;
                if (qi::parse(first, last, p, dynamic_template))
                    return (*this)(os, Value{ctx}, dynamic_template);
            }
            return os << "#ERROR#";
        }

        std::ostream& operator()(std::ostream& os, Dict const& ctx, mustache::section const& v) const {
            auto it = ctx.find(v.control.to_string());
            if (it != ctx.end())
                boost::apply_visitor(std::bind(do_section(), std::ref(os), std::placeholders::_1, std::cref(v)), it->second);
            else if (!v.sense)
                (*this)(os, Value{/*Nil*/}, v.content);

            return os;
        }

        template <typename Ctx, typename T>
        std::ostream& operator()(std::ostream& os, Ctx const&/* ctx*/, T const&/* element*/) const {
            return os << "[TBI:" << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "]";
        }

      private:
        struct do_section : boost::static_visitor<> {
            void operator()(std::ostream& os, Array const& ctx, mustache::section const& v) const {
                for(auto& item : ctx)
                    expander()(os, item, v.content);
            }
            template <typename Ctx>
            void operator()(std::ostream& os, Ctx const& ctx, mustache::section const& v) const {
                if (v.sense == truthiness(ctx))
                    expander()(os, Value(ctx), v.content);
            }
          private:
            static bool truthiness(Nil)                              { return false; }
            static bool truthiness(double d)                         { return 0. == d; }
            template <typename T> static bool truthiness(T const& v) { return !v.empty(); }
        };
    };

}

int myMain()
{
    std::cout << std::unitbuf;
    std::string input = "<ul>{{#time}}\n\t<li>{{> partial}}</li>{{/time}}</ul>\n "
        "<i>for all good men</i> to come to the {007} aid of "
        "their</bold> {{country}}. Result: {{^Res2}}(absent){{/Res2}}{{#Res2}}{{Res2}}{{/Res2}}"
        ;
    // Parser setup --------------------------------------------------------
    typedef std::string::const_iterator It;
    static const mustache_grammar<It> p;

    It first = input.begin(), last = input.end();

    try {
        mustache::sequence parsed_template;
        if (qi::parse(first, last, p, parsed_template))
        {
            std::cout << "Parse success\n";
        } else
        {
            std::cout << "Parse failed\n";
        }

        if (first != last)
        {
            std::cout << "Remaing unparsed input: '" << std::string(first, last) << "'\n";
        }

        std::cout << "Input:      " << input << "\n";
        std::cout << "Dump:       ";
        Dumping::dumper()(std::cout, parsed_template) << "\n";

        std::cout << "Evaluation: ";

        {
            using namespace ContextExpander;
            expander engine;

            Value const ctx = Dict { 
                { "time", Array {
                    Dict { { "partial", "gugus {{zeit}} (a.k.a. <u>{{title}}</u>)"},             { "title", "noon" },    { "zeit", "12:00" } },
                    Dict { { "partial", "gugus {{zeit}} (a.k.a. <u>{{title}}</u>)"},             { "title", "evening" }, { "zeit", "19:30" } },
                    Dict { { "partial", "gugus <u>{{title}}</u> (expected at around {{zeit}})"}, { "title", "dawn" },    { "zeit", "06:00" } },
                } },
                { "country", "ESP" },
                { "Res3", "unused" }
            };

            engine(std::cout, ctx, parsed_template);
        }
    } catch(qi::expectation_failure<It> const& e)
    {
        std::cout << "Unexpected: '" << std::string(e.first, e.last) << "'\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Boost Spirit is built on Proto (by the same hero, Eric Niebler!), so I hope you don't mind if I uphold a personal tradition of mine and present an implementation in Boost Spirit.

I found it pretty tricky to see what you wanted to achieve, from just the code shown. Therefore I just went straight to the **[`mustache` docs](http://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html)** and implemented a parser for the following AST:

```
namespace mustache {

    // any atom refers directly to source iterators for efficiency
    using boost::string_ref;
    template <typename Kind> struct atom {
        string_ref value;

        atom() { }
        atom(string_ref const& value) : value(value) { }
    };

    // the atoms
    using verbatim = atom<struct verbatim_tag>;
    using variable = atom<struct variable_tag>;
    using partial  = atom<struct partial_tag>;

    // the template elements (any atom or a section)
    struct section;

    using melement = boost::variant<
            verbatim,
            variable,
            partial, 
            boost::recursive_wrapper<section>
            // TODO comments and set-separators
        >;

    // the template: sequences of elements
    using sequence = std::vector<melement>;

    // section: recursively define to contain a template sequence
    struct section {
        bool       sense; // positive or negative
        string_ref control;
        sequence   content;
    };
}
```

As you can see, I've added support for *negated* sections as well as *partial* templates (i.e. variables that expand to a template to dynamically expand).

Here are the productions:

```
sequence     = *element;
element      = 
            !(lit("{{") >> '/') >> // section-end ends the current sequence
            (partial | section | variable | verbatim);

reference    = +(graph - "}}");

partial      = qi::lit("{{") >> "> " >> reference >> "}}";

sense        = ('#' > attr(true))
             | ('^' > attr(false));

section     %= "{{" >> sense >> reference [ section_id = phx::bind(&boost::string_ref::to_string, _1) ] >> "}}"
            >> sequence // contents
            > ("{{" >> ('/' >> lit(section_id)) >> "}}");

variable     = "{{" >> reference >> "}}";

verbatim     = +(char_ - "{{");
```

The only nifty thing is the use of a `qi::local<>` named `section_id` to check that the closing tag of a section matches the opening tag of the current section.

```
qi::rule<Iterator, mustache::sequence()> sequence;
qi::rule<Iterator, mustache::melement()> element;
qi::rule<Iterator, mustache::partial()>  partial;
qi::rule<Iterator, mustache::section(), qi::locals<std::string> >  section;
qi::rule<Iterator, bool()>                sense;                  // postive  or negative
qi::rule<Iterator, mustache::variable()> variable;
qi::rule<Iterator, mustache::verbatim()> verbatim;
```

I optimize things based on the assumption that the input data will stay around, so we don't need to copy actual data. This should avoid 99% of allocation needs here. I used `boost::string_ref` to achieve this here, and I think it's fair to say that this introduces the only bits of complexity (see full code below).

```
qi::rule<Iterator, boost::string_ref()>   reference;
```

Now we're ready to take our parser for a spin **See It [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f3d4a5fe7eeb98c1)**

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << std::unitbuf;
    std::string input = "<ul>{{#time}}\n\t<li>{{> partial}}</li>{{/time}}</ul>\n "
        "<i>for all good men</i> to come to the {007} aid of "
        "their</bold> {{country}}. Result: {{^Res2}}(absent){{/Res2}}{{#Res2}}{{Res2}}{{/Res2}}"
        ;
    // Parser setup --------------------------------------------------------
    typedef std::string::const_iterator It;
    static const mustache_grammar<It> p;

    It first = input.begin(), last = input.end();

    try {
        mustache::sequence parsed_template;
        if (qi::parse(first, last, p, parsed_template))
            std::cout << "Parse success\n";
        else
            std::cout << "Parse failed\n";

        if (first != last)
            std::cout << "Remaing unparsed input: '" << std::string(first, last) << "'\n";

        std::cout << "Input:      " << input << "\n";
        std::cout << "Dump:       ";
        Dumping::dumper()(std::cout, parsed_template) << "\n";
    } catch(qi::expectation_failure<It> const& e)
    {
        std::cout << "Unexpected: '" << std::string(e.first, e.last) << "'\n";
    }
}
```

`Dumping::dumper` simply prints the mustache template back from the parsed AST. You might wonder how `dumper` is implemented:

```
struct dumper : boost::static_visitor<std::ostream&>
{
    std::ostream& operator()(std::ostream& os, mustache::sequence const& v) const {
        for(auto& element : v)
            boost::apply_visitor(std::bind(dumper(), std::ref(os), std::placeholders::_1), element);
        return os;
    }
    std::ostream& operator()(std::ostream& os, mustache::verbatim const& v) const {
        return os << v.value;
    }
    std::ostream& operator()(std::ostream& os, mustache::variable const& v) const {
        return os << "{{" << v.value << "}}";
    }
    std::ostream& operator()(std::ostream& os, mustache::partial const& v) const {
        return os << "{{> " << v.value << "}}";
    }
    std::ostream& operator()(std::ostream& os, mustache::section const& v) const {
        os << "{{" << (v.sense?'#':'^') << v.control << "}}";
        (*this)(os, v.content);
        return os << "{{/" << v.control << "}}";
    }
};
```

Nothing overly complicated. Boost Variant really affords a declarative programming style. To illustrate this even more thoroughly, let's add expansion based on context objects!

I wasn't going to implement JSON just for this, so instead let's assume a context Value model like:

```
struct Nil { };

using Value = boost::make_recursive_variant<
    Nil,
    double,
    std::string,
    std::map<std::string, boost::recursive_variant_>,
    std::vector<boost::recursive_variant_>
>::type;

using Dict  = std::map<std::string, Value>;
using Array = std::vector<Value>;
```

Now we use binary visitation against `mustache::melement` and this context `Value` variant. This is a bit more code than just dumping, but let's look at the use-site first:

```
using namespace ContextExpander;
expander engine;

Value const ctx = Dict { 
    { "time", Array {
        Dict { { "partial", "gugus {{zeit}} (a.k.a. <u>{{title}}</u>)"},             { "title", "noon" },    { "zeit", "12:00" } },
        Dict { { "partial", "gugus {{zeit}} (a.k.a. <u>{{title}}</u>)"},             { "title", "evening" }, { "zeit", "19:30" } },
        Dict { { "partial", "gugus <u>{{title}}</u> (expected at around {{zeit}})"}, { "title", "dawn" },    { "zeit", "06:00" } },
    } },
    { "country", "ESP" },
    { "Res3", "unused" }
};

engine(std::cout, ctx, parsed_template);
```

This prints (**See it [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/11263c3425106091) again**):

```
Evaluation: <ul>
    <li>gugus 12:00 (a.k.a. <u>noon</u>)</li>
    <li>gugus 19:30 (a.k.a. <u>evening</u>)</li>
    <li>gugus <u>dawn</u> (expected at around 06:00)</li></ul>
 <i>for all good men</i> to come to the {007} aid of their</bold> ESP. Result: (absent)
```

#### Full Code Listing

for reference:

```
//#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_USE_PHOENIX_V3
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/struct.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/utility/string_ref.hpp>
#include <functional>
#include <map>

namespace mustache {

    // any atom refers directly to source iterators for efficiency
    using boost::string_ref;
    template <typename Kind> struct atom {
        string_ref value;

        atom() { }
        atom(string_ref const& value) : value(value) { }

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, atom const& v) { return os << typeid(v).name() << "[" << v.value << "]"; }
    };

    // the atoms
    using verbatim = atom<struct verbatim_tag>;
    using variable = atom<struct variable_tag>;
    using partial  = atom<struct partial_tag>;

    // the template elements (any atom or a section)
    struct section;

    using melement = boost::variant<
            verbatim,
            variable,
            partial, // TODO comments and set-separators
            boost::recursive_wrapper<section>
        >;

    // the template: sequences of elements
    using sequence = std::vector<melement>;

    // section: recursively define to contain a template sequence
    struct section {
        bool       sense; // positive or negative
        string_ref control;
        sequence   content;
    };
}

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(mustache::section, (bool, sense)(boost::string_ref, control)(mustache::sequence, content))

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace phx= boost::phoenix;

template <typename Iterator>
    struct mustache_grammar : qi::grammar<Iterator, mustache::sequence()>
{
    mustache_grammar() : mustache_grammar::base_type(sequence)
    {
        using namespace qi;
        static const _a_type section_id; // local
        using boost::phoenix::construct;
        using boost::phoenix::begin;
        using boost::phoenix::size;

        sequence     = *element;
        element      = 
                    !(lit("{{") >> '/') >> // section-end ends the current sequence
                    (partial | section | variable | verbatim);

        reference    = raw [ lexeme [ +(graph - "}}") ] ]
                        [ _val = construct<boost::string_ref>(&*begin(_1), size(_1)) ];

        partial      = qi::lit("{{") >> "> " >> reference >> "}}";

        sense        = ('#' > attr(true))
                    | ('^' > attr(false));

        section     %= "{{" >> sense >> reference [ section_id = phx::bind(&boost::string_ref::to_string, _1) ] >> "}}"
                    >> sequence // contents
                    > ("{{" >> ('/' >> lexeme [ lit(section_id) ]) >> "}}");

        variable     = "{{" >> reference >> "}}";

        verbatim     = raw [ lexeme [ +(char_ - "{{") ] ]
                        [ _val = construct<boost::string_ref>(&*begin(_1), size(_1)) ];

        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES(
                (sequence)(element)(partial)(variable)(section)(verbatim)
                (reference)(sense)
            )
    }
private:
    qi::rule<Iterator, mustache::sequence()> sequence;
    qi::rule<Iterator, mustache::melement()> element;
    qi::rule<Iterator, mustache::partial()>  partial;
    qi::rule<Iterator, mustache::section(), qi::locals<std::string> >  section;
    qi::rule<Iterator, bool()>                sense;                  // postive  or negative
    qi::rule<Iterator, mustache::variable()> variable;
    qi::rule<Iterator, mustache::verbatim()> verbatim;
    qi::rule<Iterator, boost::string_ref()>   reference;
};

namespace Dumping {
    struct dumper : boost::static_visitor<std::ostream&>
    {
        std::ostream& operator()(std::ostream& os, mustache::sequence const& v) const {
            for(auto& element : v)
                boost::apply_visitor(std::bind(dumper(), std::ref(os), std::placeholders::_1), element);
            return os;
        }
        std::ostream& operator()(std::ostream& os, mustache::verbatim const& v) const {
            return os << v.value;
        }
        std::ostream& operator()(std::ostream& os, mustache::variable const& v) const {
            return os << "{{" << v.value << "}}";
        }
        std::ostream& operator()(std::ostream& os, mustache::partial const& v) const {
            return os << "{{> " << v.value << "}}";
        }
        std::ostream& operator()(std::ostream& os, mustache::section const& v) const {
            os << "{{" << (v.sense?'#':'^') << v.control << "}}";
            (*this)(os, v.content);
            return os << "{{/" << v.control << "}}";
        }
    };
}

namespace ContextExpander {

    struct Nil { };

    using Value = boost::make_recursive_variant<
        Nil,
        double,
        std::string,
        std::map<std::string, boost::recursive_variant_>,
        std::vector<boost::recursive_variant_>
    >::type;

    using Dict  = std::map<std::string, Value>;
    using Array = std::vector<Value>;

    static inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Nil   const&)   { return os << "#NIL#"; }
    static inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Dict  const& v) { return os << "#DICT("  << v.size() << ")#"; }
    static inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Array const& v) { return os << "#ARRAY(" << v.size() << ")#"; }

    struct expander : boost::static_visitor<std::ostream&>
    {
        std::ostream& operator()(std::ostream& os, Value const& ctx, mustache::sequence const& v) const {
            for(auto& element : v)
                boost::apply_visitor(std::bind(expander(), std::ref(os), std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2), ctx, element);
            return os;
        }

        template <typename Ctx>
        std::ostream& operator()(std::ostream& os, Ctx const&/*ignored*/, mustache::verbatim const& v) const {
            return os << v.value;
        }

        std::ostream& operator()(std::ostream& os, Dict const& ctx, mustache::variable const& v) const {
            auto it = ctx.find(v.value.to_string());
            if (it != ctx.end())
                os << it->second;
            return os;
        }

        template <typename Ctx>
        std::ostream& operator()(std::ostream& os, Ctx const&, mustache::variable const&) const {
            return os;
        }

        std::ostream& operator()(std::ostream& os, Dict const& ctx, mustache::partial const& v) const {
            auto it = ctx.find(v.value.to_string());
            if (it != ctx.end())
            {
                static const mustache_grammar<std::string::const_iterator> p;

                auto const& subtemplate = boost::get<std::string>(it->second);
                std::string::const_iterator first = subtemplate.begin(), last = subtemplate.end();

                mustache::sequence dynamic_template;
                if (qi::parse(first, last, p, dynamic_template))
                    return (*this)(os, Value{ctx}, dynamic_template);
            }
            return os << "#ERROR#";
        }

        std::ostream& operator()(std::ostream& os, Dict const& ctx, mustache::section const& v) const {
            auto it = ctx.find(v.control.to_string());
            if (it != ctx.end())
                boost::apply_visitor(std::bind(do_section(), std::ref(os), std::placeholders::_1, std::cref(v)), it->second);
            else if (!v.sense)
                (*this)(os, Value{/*Nil*/}, v.content);

            return os;
        }

        template <typename Ctx, typename T>
        std::ostream& operator()(std::ostream& os, Ctx const&/* ctx*/, T const&/* element*/) const {
            return os << "[TBI:" << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "]";
        }

    private:
        struct do_section : boost::static_visitor<> {
            void operator()(std::ostream& os, Array const& ctx, mustache::section const& v) const {
                for(auto& item : ctx)
                    expander()(os, item, v.content);
            }
            template <typename Ctx>
            void operator()(std::ostream& os, Ctx const& ctx, mustache::section const& v) const {
                if (v.sense == truthiness(ctx))
                    expander()(os, Value(ctx), v.content);
            }
        private:
            static bool truthiness(Nil)                              { return false; }
            static bool truthiness(double d)                         { return 0. == d; }
            template <typename T> static bool truthiness(T const& v) { return !v.empty(); }
        };
    };

}

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::unitbuf;
    std::string input = "<ul>{{#time}}\n\t<li>{{> partial}}</li>{{/time}}</ul>\n "
        "<i>for all good men</i> to come to the {007} aid of "
        "their</bold> {{country}}. Result: {{^Res2}}(absent){{/Res2}}{{#Res2}}{{Res2}}{{/Res2}}"
        ;
    // Parser setup --------------------------------------------------------
    typedef std::string::const_iterator It;
    static const mustache_grammar<It> p;

    It first = input.begin(), last = input.end();

    try {
        mustache::sequence parsed_template;
        if (qi::parse(first, last, p, parsed_template))
        {
            std::cout << "Parse success\n";
        } else
        {
            std::cout << "Parse failed\n";
        }

        if (first != last)
        {
            std::cout << "Remaing unparsed input: '" << std::string(first, last) << "'\n";
        }

        std::cout << "Input:      " << input << "\n";
        std::cout << "Dump:       ";
        Dumping::dumper()(std::cout, parsed_template) << "\n";

        std::cout << "Evaluation: ";

        {
            using namespace ContextExpander;
            expander engine;

            Value const ctx = Dict { 
                { "time", Array {
                    Dict { { "partial", "gugus {{zeit}} (a.k.a. <u>{{title}}</u>)"},             { "title", "noon" },    { "zeit", "12:00" } },
                    Dict { { "partial", "gugus {{zeit}} (a.k.a. <u>{{title}}</u>)"},             { "title", "evening" }, { "zeit", "19:30" } },
                    Dict { { "partial", "gugus <u>{{title}}</u> (expected at around {{zeit}})"}, { "title", "dawn" },    { "zeit", "06:00" } },
                } },
                { "country", "ESP" },
                { "Res3", "unused" }
            };

            engine(std::cout, ctx, parsed_template);
        }
    } catch(qi::expectation_failure<It> const& e)
    {
        std::cout << "Unexpected: '" << std::string(e.first, e.last) << "'\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: You could specialize assign_to_attribute_from_iterators trait to avoid the phoenix hack for string_ref. btw, [here](https://github.com/jamboree/bustache)'s yet another impl using non-offical Spirit.

Comment: @Jamboree Yup. i'm aware of that :) I tend not to introduce extensions just for a demonstration of Spirit. In my own code base I'd use the traits indeed. Thanks for reviewing my answer :)

Comment: @Jamboree hehe. I noticed your project comes with a JSON-like model. How (if at all) do you resolve the problem that e.g. `bustache::value x = "hello world"` would assign `bool` value `1` to `x` ?

Comment: Well, I didn't resolve that, and that's why you see I spell out std::string explicitly in the [demo](https://github.com/jamboree/bustache/blob/master/main.cpp#L13).
That said, in c++1y we could use "hello world"s.

Comment: @sehe Wow you are awesome man. I was getting some serious doubts since yesterday if it is at all possible to implement it with XPressive, so I secretly began to read myself into *Spirit*. Seems so easy at first sight but has so many small but important details to remember... So your example will greatly help, thanks a bunch mate! I'll have a look at it later today and report and rate it. :D

Comment: @sehe Interesting detail: I can't even compile your code under g++ at all. Neither on my mingw4.9, nor on Coliru nor another online compiler. Why is it only running under CLANG? :-O

Comment: No clue. Are you using [the compiler options as shown](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/11263c3425106091) (notably, `-std=c++11`?)

Comment: @sehe Yessir, all the same options. Gcc on Coliru is v4.8, mine locally is 4.9 with Boost 1.55. What are you using locally and on what os?

Comment: I've used gcc 4.8, 4.9, clang 3.4 and on Coliru clang (because gcc is too slow there...). I just retested on Ubuntu 13.10 64bit, gcc 4.8.1 (stock) _(PS. it might be surprising, but if you hand me a piece of recently worn clothing, or maybe a piece of the compiler message, my psychic abilities would really be boosted)_

Comment: You can try this version which avoids the messy semantic action: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/313648b0eb9dfc61

Comment: @sehe I was afraid you would ask for my worn undies... ok gimme your home address man *sob*. And sorry but the error messages are too long for this message :(

Comment: assuming _sob_ was not an acronym there :) (I think my psychic abilities might have done ok there, though, so just don't mail it yet)

Comment: @sehe Okay so far this one compiles, thanks a lot. Can you edit your above solution post or should I post the new code myself here as a reference?

Comment: It's already posted here, right? I _can_ edit of course, although I'd rather find out the cause and file a bug with GCC or boost :)

Comment: @Jamboree, I'm looking at your library and it looks really nice!  One thing that I am VERY interested in seeing is how to build a bustache::object programmatically using its member functions.  Probably asking way too much, but how difficult would it be to enhance bustache::object to take a JSON string overload argument?

Comment: @CarolineBeltran It's just a `boost::unordered_map` (much like the std one). You can do whatever you want with it, but for JSON string, you need to parse it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a recursive descent parser. One is discussed here http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/recursive-descent-peg-parsers-using-c-te/212700432

Comment: XPressive does it too (see the docs). But what am I doing wrong? But thanks for the link.