# Problems with boost::phoenix::bind and boost::phoenix::actors in a semantic action for boost::spirit::qi

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-phoenix

I think I am having an issue understanding how my `boost::spirit::qi` parser is supposed to be written.  I simply want to pass matched substrings to functions via semantic actions.  In an attempt to roughly emulate [this boost tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/tutorials/semantic_actions.html), I have come up with the following code:

```
template<class Iterator> 
struct _Calculator : public qi::grammar<Iterator> {                                                                                               

    qi::rule<Iterator> number, result; //and a whole bunch of other ones too                                                            

    qi::rule<Iterator,std::string()> variable;                                                                                      

    Code& code;                                                                                                    
    Variables& variables;                                                                                                          

    _Calculator(Code& code_, Variables& variables_)
      : _Calculator::base_type(result),                                                                                                           
        code(code_),
        variables(variables_)                                                                                                                     
   {  
          number =
                lexeme[(qi::char_("1-9") >> +qi::char_("0-9"))[boost::phoenix::bind(&fPushIntCV, qi::_1, boost::ref(code), boost::ref(variables))]]
              | lexeme[("0x" >> +qi::char_("0-9a-fA-F"))      [boost::phoenix::bind(&fPushIntCV, qi::_1, boost::ref(code), boost::ref(variables))]]
              | lexeme[("0b" >> +qi::char_("0-1"))            [boost::phoenix::bind(&fPushIntCV, qi::_1, boost::ref(code), boost::ref(variables))]]
              | lexeme[("0" >>  +qi::char_("0-7"))            [boost::phoenix::bind(&fPushIntCV, qi::_1, boost::ref(code), boost::ref(variables))]]
          //some other junk
    }
};
typedef _Calculator<std::string::const_iterator> Calculator;
```

When the declaration of `fPushIntCV` looks like this:

```
void fPushIntCV (vector<char> my_str, Code& c, Variables& v);
```

I get this error:

`function_ptr.hpp:89: error: conversion from 'char' to non-scalar type 'std::vector<char, std::allocator<char> >' requested`

When I  change the declaration of `fPushIntCV` to look like this:

```
void fPushIntCV (char my_str, Code& c, Variables& v);
```

I get this error:

`function_ptr.hpp:89: error: cannot convert 'std::vector<char, std::allocator<char> >' to 'char' in argument passing`

I figured that the attribute of `qi::_1` is changing, but I get unresolved references if I include both function prototypes and now pass `boost::phoenix::bind` some ambiguous overloaded function pointer:

`error: no matching function for call to 'bind(<unresolved overloaded function type>, const boost::spirit::_1_type&, ...` (my `...` for trailing unrelated garbage)

I know this is probably a really simple error and a really simple fix, but I'm having a helluva time understanding the spell to make the boost magic do its thing.  What is the function prototype that this semantic action is expecting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few observations:

- You don't seem to be using a skipper, so using `lexeme` is redundant (see [Boost spirit skipper issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17072987/boost-spirit-skipper-issues/17073965#17073965))
- You want to know how to detect the type of the attribute exposed by a parser expression: see [Detecting the parameter types in a Spirit semantic action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9404189/detecting-the-parameter-types-in-a-spirit-semantic-action)

  The types are documented with the parser directives, though, so e.g. `as_string[(qi::char_("1-9") >> +qi::char_("0-9"))]` results in `boost::fusion::vector2<char, std::vector<char> >`, which is directly reflected in the error message on GCC:

  ```
  boost/phoenix/bind/detail/preprocessed/function_ptr_10.hpp|50 col 39| error: could not convert ‘a0’ from ‘boost::fusion::vector2<char, std::vector<char> >’ to ‘std::vector<char>’
  ```
- Prefer not to mix and match library placeholders/wrappers, e.g. `boost::ref` and `boost::phoenix::ref`
- You seem to be reinventing integer parsing; consider using `qi::int_parser` instead
- It seems that the case to parse `0` is missing :)

Assuming you want `my_str` to simply reflect the input string including number base prefix, I could suggest using:

```
number =
     as_string[(qi::char_("1-9") >> +qi::char_("0-9"))] [phx::bind(&fPushIntCV, qi::_1, phx::ref(code), phx::ref(variables))]
   | as_string[("0x" >> +qi::char_("0-9a-fA-F"))      ] [phx::bind(&fPushIntCV, qi::_1, phx::ref(code), phx::ref(variables))]
   | as_string[("0b" >> +qi::char_("0-1"))            ] [phx::bind(&fPushIntCV, qi::_1, phx::ref(code), phx::ref(variables))]
   | as_string[("0" >>  +qi::char_("0-7"))            ] [phx::bind(&fPushIntCV, qi::_1, phx::ref(code), phx::ref(variables))]
   //some other junk
   ;
```

However, this could be simplified to:

```
number = as_string[
       (qi::char_("1-9") >> +qi::char_("0-9"))
     | ("0x" >> +qi::char_("0-9a-fA-F"))
     | ("0b" >> +qi::char_("01"))
     | ("0"  >> +qi::char_("0-7"))
   ]        [phx::bind(&fPushIntCV, qi::_1, phx::ref(code), phx::ref(variables))]
   ;
```

Now, you would probably like to just parse an integer value instead:

```
number = 
     ( 
       ("0x" >> qi::int_parser<int, 16, 1>())
     | ("0b" >> qi::int_parser<int,  2, 1>())
     | ("0"  >> qi::int_parser<int,  8, 1>())
     | qi::int_ /* accepts "0" */) [phx::bind(&fPushIntCV, qi::_1, phx::ref(code), phx::ref(variables))]
   ;
```

Which handsomely does the conversions<sup>**[1]**</sup>, and you can just take an `int`:

```
void fPushIntCV (int my_number, Code& c, Variables& v) {
    std::cout << "fPushIntCV: " << my_number << "\n";
}
```

<sup>**[1]**</sup> *(there's also `uint_parser` and you can parse `long`, `long long` etc.; even big integers like `boost::multiprecision::cpp_int` should be no issue)*

Here's a demo program using this, showing that the values are converted correctly (and: "0" is accepted :)): **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d908e426407aad0f)**

```
int main()
{
    Code code;
    Variables variables;
    Calculator g(code, variables); 

    for (std::string const input : { "0", "0xef1A", "010", "0b10101" })
    {
        It f(input.begin()), l(input.end());

        if(qi::parse(f, l, g))
            std::cout << "Parse success ('" << input << "')\n";
        else std::cout << "Parse failed ('" << input << "')\n";

        if (f != l)
            std::cout << "Input remaining: '" << std::string(f, l) << "'\n";
    }
}
```

Prints

```
fPushIntCV: 0
Parse success ('0')

fPushIntCV: 61210
Parse success ('0xef1A')

fPushIntCV: 8
Parse success ('010')

fPushIntCV: 21
Parse success ('0b10101')
```

Comment: It is my understanding that copying strings can be a noticeable performance hit.  Is there a way to pass my function `string::iterator` instead of a full blown `string`?

Comment: Note, in my final offering I don't pass strings at all. Otherwise, you can use `qi::raw[]` to pass the iterators instead. I've used this with `boost::string_ref` in the past: **[a mustache parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24122557/how-to-parse-mustache-with-boost-xpressive-correctly/24131286#24131286)** and **[a CSV parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23699731/simplest-way-to-read-a-csv-file-mapped-to-memory/23703810#23703810)**

Comment: I am upgrading some old `boost::spirit::classic` code, and sadly the rather complex action functions expected `char* start, char *end`.  I am revamping the system to use `boost::spirit::qi` for easy performance boosts and cleaner, more modern code, however I haven't gotten into the nitty-gritty details yet to perform optimizations that do away with strings altogether (although it is certainly on the todo list).  For now, I am just trying to increase string performance as much as possible.

Comment: Okay.  Seems that qi::raw is the way to go then, for quick results