# Calculate allocated memory of std::string (and the use of strings in std::vector)

Tags: c++, string, memory, sizeof, allocation

I want to calculate how much memory is allocated when I create and assign values to a string.

```
string s = "";
cout << sizeof(s) << endl;
cout << sizeof(s.at(0)) * s.capacity() << endl;
s = "1234567890qwertz";
cout << sizeof(s) << endl;
cout << sizeof(s.at(0)) * s.capacity() << endl;
```

Is this all memory that my string s consumes? The initial/static part that I get by simply calling sizeof(s) (being 40 bytes on my machine) **plus** the dynamic part - the size of one character times the allocated placeholders for making strings efficiently resizable (on my machine the string s first allocated a block of 15 bytes until the point where the text is too long, so after the second assignment the dynamic part is 31 bytes). Why not 16 and 32 bytes by the way?

Is this way of thinking about it (static + dynamic for each string is all the memory it occupies) correct?

Meaning that if I have a std::vector of strings, and I wanted to calculate all the memory for that vector as well, I would need to kind of do the same thing: I add the initial/static size of my vector to get the plus the dynamic part which means the total memory occupied by one string the way I do it above for each string inside the vector?

```
vector<string> cache;
// fill cache with strings of dynamic length
int size = sizeof(cache);
for (int i = 0; i < cache.size(); i++)
{
    size += sizeof(cache[i]);
    size += sizeof(cache[i].at(0)) * cache[i].capacity();
}
```

So to sum it all up, is that the correct amount of memory occupied by my "cache"?

**Edit:**
Or do I also need to take into account that a std::vector itself also has a .capacity() >= .size() which could mean that I would actually need to do this:

for each `cache.capacity()` - I would need to add `sizeof(cache[i])` and additionally
for each `cache.size()` - add `sizeof(cache[i].at(0)) * cache[i].capacity()` ??

Comment: *I want to calculate how much memory is allocated when I create and assign values to a string* -- Ok, I'll ask.  Why do you need this information?

Comment: `sizeof(s)` is the size of the *object* `s`, not the string itself. Unless there's some short-string optimization (which stores the contents inside the actual string object), then a `std::string` is really nothing more than a couple of sizes and a pointer to the actual string data.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Do those 40 or those couples of sizes and a pointer to the actual data add up as I put more and more string objects into a std::vector?

Comment: To your side question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11752722/3552770

Comment: Of course, each `std::string` object will need space.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I create a software data cache (simply a vector of strings) and I want to know how my memory grows as I put more elements (strings) into it. So that I can say - when it would become bigger than 40KB I want to clear the cache and so on...

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude So it is correct to do something like for each string in vector: sizeof(s) (which is 40 on my machine) + [dynamically allocated size of that string]?

Comment: @LogicStuff Ahh yes makes sense. Thank you. I forgot about that one.

Comment: If you care about 40KB you may avoid using `std::vector<std::string>>` in this case.

Comment: Get free memory before and after string instantiation.

Comment: @huzzm yes, although some strings might not allocate memory at all.

Comment: @Slava That might be true, but I still do care about an answer to my question.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Oh really, how come?

Comment: @huzzm global / static strings with small string optimization.

Comment: The `std::string` class has a `size()` method which will give you its size in bytes

Comment: @Nadir more accurately, `size()` returns the number of valid `char`s in the string. It does not care whether the chars are stored in dynamic memory or in an internal SSO buffer. The `capacity()` returns the actual number of chars allocated, but it also does not differentiate between dynamic and SSO memory. You can't get the true byte size of a `std::string` without knowing the internal details of its implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is going to be hard to answer.  Naively you would think the total amount of memory consumed would be

```
vector_capacity * sizeof(std::string) + sum_of_capacity_of_each_string_in_the_vector
```

But this is more an upper limit, not what could be actually consumed.  For instance, [short string optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10315041/meaning-of-acronym-sso-in-the-context-of-stdstring) allows `std::string` to store the string data in the storage the string object itself consumes (what you call the static size).  If that is the case then the actual space consumed would be

```
vector_capacity * sizeof(std::string)
```

and the capacity of each string in the vector would just be how much space you take up without allocating any extra space.  You will need to check your implementation to see if it uses SSO and long of a string it will store in the string object to actually know if the capacity value is using the strings internal space or actually consuming additional memory. That makes the actual space consumed

```
vector_capacity * sizeof(std::string) + sum_of_capacity_of_each_string_in_the_vector_where_
                                        the_capcity_is_more_than_the_sso_amount
```

---

In you calculation `sizeof(cache[i].at(0))` is not needed.  `std::string` use `char` and `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be `1`

Comment: Thank you very much. This was the kind of answer I was looking for.

Comment: You don't need the implementation details per se; you just need to know when a string allocates new memory. This can be done by e.g. [using a custom allocator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26132207/752976).

Comment: I edited the question again a little bit because a vector has a capacity >= size as well. Does that change anything or does a capacity of 15 while there are just 3 strings inside the vector mean that it is actually 15 * sizeof(string) + 3 * _dynamic memory of each single string (capacity * size of char)_

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Ok. Thanks!

Comment: @huzzm It does.  I've updated the answer to use `vector_capacity * sizeof(std::string)`

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple reason why the capacity of the string is one less than you expect and that is

```
s.c_str()
```

A C++ string is stored in a block of memory with capacity giving the total size and size for the used space. But a C string is 0 terminated. The C++ string reserve one extra byte at the end of the block of memory to store a 0. That way `s.c_str()` is always 0 terminated.

So the memory used by the dynamic part of the string is capacity + 1.

As to the total memory consumed by a string or vector of strings NathanOliver answered that I think. But beware of vectors holding the same string multiple times.

Comment: Oh yes, very true. I forgot about the null termination. Thanks for the additional answer!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know how much space your `std::vector<std::string>` uses, calculate it:

```
auto netto_memory_use(std::vector<std::string> const& x) noexcept {
    return std::accumulate(
        begin(x),
        end(x),
        sizeof x + sizeof x[0] * x.capacity(),
        [](auto n, auto&& s) {
            if (std::less<void*>()(data(s), &s)
            || std::greater_eq<void*>()(data(s) + s.capacity(), &s + 1))
                return n + s.capacity() + 1;
            return n;
        });
    }
```

I used `std::less<void*>` / `std::greater_eq<void*>` to take advantage of them defining a full order, in contrast to just using the comparison-operators.

The accumulator tests for applied small-string-optimisation (SSO) before adding the string's capactiy. Of course, all 0-capacity strings could share the same statically-allocated terminator. Or capacity and/or length could be allocated together with the character-data.
Still, that should be a good approximation for the memory used, aside from memory-management-system overhead.

Comment: What is `data()`?

Comment: @Bouncner [`std::data()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/data) found per ADL.