# C++: Fast way to read mapped file into a matrix

Tags: c++, memory, boost

I'm trying to read a mapped file into a matrix. The file is something like this:

```
name;phone;city\n
Luigi Rossi;02341567;Milan\n
Mario Bianchi;06567890;Rome\n
....
```

and it's quiet big. The code I've written works properly but it's not so fast:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/iostreams/device/mapped_file.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int i;
    int j=0;
    int k=0;

    vector< vector<char> > M(10000000, vector<string>(3));

    mapped_file_source file("file.csv");

    // Check if file was successfully opened
    if(file.is_open()) {

      // Get pointer to the data
      const char * c = (const char *)file.data();

      int size=file.size();

      for(i = 0; i < (size+1); i++){

       if(c[i]=='\n' || i==size){
        j=j+1;
        k=0;
       }else if(c[i]==';'){
        k=k+1;
       }else{
        M[j][k]+=c[i];
       }    
     }//end for


   }//end if    

 return(0)


}
```

Is there a faster way? I've read something about memcyp but I don't know how to use it to speed up my code.

Comment: Unless you have close to ten million entries in the file, you are wasting quite a lot of memory. You might want to consider `std::deque` instead perhaps? Or just letting `std::vector` handle it. And if you're just loading this collections once, will the "effectiveness" of this part of the code really impact the total runtime of the program by such a large percentage?

Comment: Oh, and when writing an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), you should perhaps make sure that it actually builds. The declaration of `M` is inconsistent with the initialization.

Comment: I'm not sure if boost's `mapped_file_source` supports it, but on POSIX `mmap`'s `MAP_PRIVATE` means you can write to the memory representing the file without affecting the file (or other processes memory mapping it too).  With that, one very fast option is to overwrite `;` and `\n` characters with NULs, then keep `const char*`s and/or integral offsets to the start of the textual values instead of separate `std::string` objects.  If you're ***really*** serious about speed and memory efficiency, I'd suggest trying that (even if it means bypassing boost).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg:  soory, this is the right code: vector< vector<string> > M(1000000, vector<string>(3));

Comment: @TonyD boost supports it

Answer (score 7):

I have numerous examples doing this/similar written up on SO.

Let me list the most relevant:

- I've done quite a few of these benchmarks. Yes, for sequential freading, read/scanf have a tiny edge (see e.g. [scanf/iostreams and files vs. mappings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17479702/85371), and [parsing floats](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23439161/85371), or [read being slightly faster for 1-pass sequential read](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25150519/85371)).
- An interesting approach is to do parsing lazily (why copy the whole input into memory? What's the point memory mapping then). The answer here shows this approach (emulating a multimap there):

  - [Using boost::iostreams::mapped_file_source with std::multimap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28217301/using-boostiostreamsmapped-file-source-with-stdmultimap/28220864#28220864) (approach #2)

In all other cases, consider slamming a Spirit Qi job on it, potentially using `boost::string_ref` instead of `vector<char>` (unless the mapped file is not "const", of course).

The `string_ref` is also shown int the last answer linked before. Another interesting example of this (with lazy conversions to un-escaped string values) is here [How to parse mustache with Boost.Xpressive correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24122557/how-to-parse-mustache-with-boost-xpressive-correctly/24131286#24131286)

### DEMO

Here's that Qi job slammed on it:

- it parses a 994 MiB file of ~32 million lines in 2.9s into a vector of

  ```
  struct Line {
      boost::string_ref name, city;
      long id;
  };
  ```
- note that we parse the number, and store the strings by referring to their location in the memory map + length (`string_ref`)
- it pretty-prints the data from 10 random lines
- it can run as fast as 2.5s if you reserve 32m elements in the vector at once; the program does only a single memory allocation in that case.
- NOTE: on a 64 bit system, the memory representation grows larger than the input size if the average line length is less than 40 bytes. This is because a `string_ref` is 16 bytes.

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c1f11b11bc059c1e)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/struct.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/device/mapped_file.hpp>
#include <boost/utility/string_ref.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
using sref   = boost::string_ref;

namespace boost { namespace spirit { namespace traits {
    template <typename It>
    struct assign_to_attribute_from_iterators<sref, It, void> {
        static void call(It f, It l, sref& attr) { attr = { f, size_t(std::distance(f,l)) }; }
    };
} } }

struct Line {
    sref name, city;
    long id;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Line, (sref,name)(long,id)(sref,city))

int main() {
    boost::iostreams::mapped_file_source mmap("input.txt");

    using namespace qi;

    std::vector<Line> parsed;
    parsed.reserve(32000000);
    if (phrase_parse(mmap.begin(), mmap.end(), 
                omit[+graph] >> eol >>
                (raw[*~char_(";\r\n")] >> ';' >> long_ >> ';' >> raw[*~char_(";\r\n")]) % eol,
                qi::blank, parsed))
    {
        std::cout << "Parsed " << parsed.size() << " lines\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "Failed after " << parsed.size() << " lines\n";
    }

    std::cout << "Printing 10 random items:\n";
    for(int i=0; i<10; ++i) {
        auto& line = parsed[rand() % parsed.size()];
        std::cout << "city: '" << line.city << "', id: " << line.id << ", name: '" << line.name << "'\n";
    }
}
```

With input generated like

```
do grep -v "'" /etc/dictionaries-common/words | sort -R | xargs -d\\n -n 3 | while read a b c; do echo "$a $b;$RANDOM;$c"; done
```

The output is e.g.

```
Parsed 31609499 lines
Printing 10 random items:
city: 'opted', id: 14614, name: 'baronets theosophy'
city: 'denominated', id: 24260, name: 'insignia ophthalmic'
city: 'mademoiselles', id: 10791, name: 'smelter orienting'
city: 'ducked', id: 32155, name: 'encircled flippantly'
city: 'garotte', id: 3080, name: 'keeling South'
city: 'emirs', id: 14511, name: 'Aztecs vindicators'
city: 'characteristically', id: 5473, name: 'constancy Troy'
city: 'savvy', id: 3921, name: 'deafer terrifically'
city: 'misfitted', id: 14617, name: 'Eliot chambray'
city: 'faceless', id: 24481, name: 'shade forwent'
```

Comment: Added a live demo that parsed ~500mb/s and pretty prints 10 random records to prove it.

Comment: I like this approach, I'll try it and let you know! Thanks!

Comment: If you find this method taking too much memory I'd suggest taking either approach #1 or #2 from [the linked answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28217301/using-boostiostreamsmapped-file-source-with-stdmultimap/28220864#28220864). Of course it's hard to tell without knowing what you actually _want to do_ with the data (and how it's organized)

Comment: I'm guessing this depended on an older Boost version, although I can't tell which.