# phrase_parse() regular expression in boost

Tags: boost

I would like to use `phrase_parse()` of boost.

I don't know %, eol, omit, raw and so on.

```
phrase_parse(
    omit\[+graph\] >> eol >> 
    (raw\[*~char_(";\r\n")\] >> ';' >> long_ >> ';' >> raw\[*~char_(";\r\n")\]) % eol, 
     qi::blank, parsed);
```

Code from: [C++: Fast way to read mapped file into a matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28340430/c-fast-way-to-read-mapped-file-into-a-matrix)

Where can I find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the Boost Spirit library. What you are looking at are [expression templates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_templates): they form an [embedded Domain Specific Language](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?EmbeddedDomainSpecificLanguage) for specifying grammar rules.

The answer explicitly mentions it:

> *In all other cases, consider slamming a Spirit Qi job on it*

And you could have seen the headers being included.

Look in the boost spirit documentation:

- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/index.html
- reference: [link](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference.html)
- specifically: [operators](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/operator.html) and [directives](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/directive.html)